# Regex - match digits after first three

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some numbers such as

```
;201000129712 
;20100054129712 
;202343234 
;203234234325 
;204234325654
```

And i want to exclude the first `;20x` and match the rest of the numbers.

Here are my attempts so far.

```
^;20([0-9])

^(;20\d)

^[\;]\d{2}?\d
```

Comment: Do you really need regex for this? Why not just `.Substring(3)`?

Comment: I am passing down the regex patterns to a mobile. So yes, i need the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookbehind regex:

```
(?<=;20)\d+
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB4zZ6/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
 Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^;\d{3}(\d+)$");
```

You want to include the semi colon, then three digits, then capture all subsequent digits using a back reference until the end of the line.

Or if you are bulk processing a multi line string:

```
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"^;\d{3}(\d+)$");
```